# I need help regarding zina

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, sex, zina, forgiveness

I’m a female and I’ve committed zina .
how to seek forgiveness?
I don’t want to continue it anymore
How to start practicing ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I committed zina (adulatery) and I feel ashamed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35110/i-committed-zina-adulatery-and-i-feel-ashamed)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Note that generally "how to" questions are of a type that might attract subjective answers which are a bad fir for our site and model. For further information about the stackexchange model I strongly recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. Further you may find [this question about the process of repentance](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41427/does-the-process-of-repentance-differ-significantly-based-on-the-sin) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Zina is a major sin in Islam. If you have committed it stop it right now. Make a promise to Allah not to do it again and repent and ask forgiveness from Allah. He is forgives anyone who repents.
Jazakallah Khairan

Answer (score 0):

May Allah SWT add more faith in your heart.
Islam has four to  five conditions for Allah SWT to accept your repentance and forgive your sins, surely he will forgive you if you do the following insha'Allah:

1. Your act of repentance must be sincerely for Allah The Almighty alone.
2. You must feel remorse and guilt over the actions so much so that you regret doing it.
3. You must immediately cease committing the wrong and sinful act, don't postpone it.
4. You must have a firm intention to never commit the sin again.