# I hit someone’s car by accident and left can allah forgive me

Tags: allah, sin, forgiveness

I hit someone’s car as I was leaving a car park, I checked the damage and I couldn’t see any. As I was about to leave I had a quick look again as I was driving and I saw a small crack.

Mistakenly I left the car park and went home, but then I couldn’t stop thinking about it. So I tried to find if I have committed a sin that Allah won’t forgive me for. While searching I saw a brother asked a similar question and the answer was that he committed a sin that Allah won’t forgive him for. I went back to see if the car is still there or not, but it was gone and now I’m so scared! Will Allah forgive me? And what can I do now I can’t find the person and what will happen if they don’t forgive me.

Comment: You can find the owner if you want. Check to see if the parking lot has cameras, check time and then find the car number. Put up a post on a social media group, go to the park and put up a flyer saying what you did and you'd like to compensate ... it can be done if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Allah forgives all sincere repentance to Him. But, He doesn't forgive the rights of other people. Those people have to forgive themselves.

It is possible they forgive in this life or the Day of Judgement.

It is possible you pay them back in this life.

It is possible they do not forgive nor do you pay them back in this world. Then, a person needs to pay some of his good deeds to that person on the Day of Judgement according to the seriousness of the sin.

A crack on a car is not the hugest crime. In the worst case scenario, a person would need to pay back good deeds equal to the trouble that caused.

But, you should repent to Allah and pray for that person since you cannot find him, and it is hoped your prayer is enough payment in this world.

Answer (score 0):

Allah subhana wa-ta'Ala's mercy surpasses his wrath (1), and the way to gain this mercy is to ask for forgiveness. Remember Adam Alay-hi ’s-salām's dua:

> رَبَّنَا ظَلَمْنَا أَنْفُسَنَا وَإِنْ لَمْ تَغْفِرْ لَنَا وَتَرْحَمْنَا لَنَكُونَنَّ مِنَ الْخَاسِرِينَ
>
> “Our Lord, we have wronged ourselves, and if You do not forgive us and have mercy upon us, we will surely be among the losers.”
> — Surah Al A’raf verse 23

It sounds like you genuinely regret your actions which is part of repentance:

> Abdullah ibn Mas’ud reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Regret is part of repentance.”
>
> Source: [Sunan Ibn Mājah 4252](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2012/09/13/regret-part-of-tawbah/)
>
> Grade: Sahih (authentic) according to Al-Albani

Further the fact you went back to find their car, shows you have put in the extra effort required to follow through on making good in your bad deed. There is a hadith that I think covers a similar situation (except from before a calamity strikes, not after):

> Anas ibn Malik reported: A man said, “O Messenger of Allah, should I tie my camel and trust in Allah, or should I leave her untied and trust in Allah?” The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Tie her and trust in Allah.”
>
> Source: [Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2517](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2012/11/17/trust-allah-tie-your-camel/)
>
> Grade: Hasan (fair) according to Al-Albani

By returning back, I believe you have done the same as the man tying the camel. You might rely on Allah subhana wa-ta'Ala for forgiveness but you also went to right the wrong you committed.

If Allah had wanted you would have found the car's owner. Had Allah decreed against it you could have never found them despite searching for your entire life. And verily is our entire life in the hands of Allah!

The fact you have been spared having to apologize in person and pay for the damage could well be a blessing from Allah subhana wa-ta'Ala (although I won't go as for as to say that it must be, only Allah knows for sure.)

And perhaps the accidental damage to the car somehow benefits the owner. For example, there is the example of al-Khadir damaging the boats in Surah al-Kahf, to prevent their theft.

Only Allah knows what will happen on the day of judgement, but perhaps insha'Allah you will be shielded from the car owner's anger because of the good steps you took to undo the damage, or some hidden blessing for them that was in that incident.

Continue seeking forgiveness from Allah and ask from Allah that the car owner forgives you — do not worry too much about the car owner themself, now that you have looked for them, and focus on asking Allah for forgiveness.

---

1. [Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 3194, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2751](https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2012/03/08/allah-rahmah-prevails-wrath/)